# How to sync a MySQL databases between two remote databases (without MySQL database replication technique )

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have two shared server (Server 1 and server 2) and one dedicated server.in the dedicated server i am running a script that will insert data in to server 1.

Now i want to sync all data from the sever 1 to server 2 in each month (Basically keeping backup database)

For the Server 1 and 2 , i dont have root access . So i have to do it in the Dedicated server.

is there any way that i can do using mysql -host  -u  -p  comment ??

if there is any other idea , can you help me out ?

Comment: "*(Basically keeping backup database)*" In that case, why not backup the database and restore it on the other server?

Comment: I want to do it in automated way .

Comment: add a last_modified timestamp field with default=now for the replicated tables at the master server and have a daemon updating the slave databases from time to time.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine, thank you for your Quick response, Can you give me a small description about it. or any tutorial url ?

Comment: You should look at mysqldump - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html.  I don't think it requires root (just permission to access the database(s) you want to dump from the user you are connecting as), and will allow you to dump all the database from one database and reload it into another.

Comment: If two servers are accessible from from one host, then these Schema and Data [Synchronization tools](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) can help you. You could run them in command line mode.

Comment: I don't have the time to detail the solution (that is why I'm commenting instead of answering), but google for "optimistic replication" to get the general picture.

Comment: @AbhilashJoseph You can (and should!) create backups in an automated way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question states to sync **all** data from one server to another, I think you can use a relatively simple solution, involving `mysqldump`.

I think you can do this all from the dedicated server:

```
mysqldump --user=<username> --password=<password> --host=<server 1 hostname> --port=<port> --add-drop-database <database name> > dump.sql
```

Replace `<username>`, `<password>`, `<port>` and `<server 1 hostname>` with the connection details for server 1.  Replace  with the name of the database on server 1 you want to copy to server 2.  If you want to copy all database, replace with the --all-databases option.

This will make a file called `dump.sql` in the current directory.  You can then load this into server 2:

```
mysql --user=<username> --password=<password> --host=<server 2 hostname> --port=<port> <database name> < dump.sql
```

Replace `<username>`, `<password>`, `<port>` and `<server 2 hostname>` with the connection details for server 2.

This will take the dump.sql file, and load it into the database on server 2.  This will drop the database on server 2 - so all existing data will be replaced with that in `dump.sql`.

Check the options to mysqldump (regarding drop databases, drop tables etc) and tailor the above commands to be suitable for your situation.  I think, if you hook things up correctly, you could even bypass the intermediate file and connect the mysqldump on server 1 to mysql on server 2 using a socket.

To cover the 'automated' part of this question, you could run the above commands under cron and schedule them to run on the first day of every month at a suitable time.

Answer (score 0):

AS @MarkStreatfield already said, mysqldump is just for you. You don't need to be root to run it.
However, you should keep in mind that while dump processing is in process there is a global lock on all tables, so your app is not fully functional at this moment. If you are passing mysqldump output directly to server2, it might take significant time so it can be a problem.

For backup purposes, it's better to dump to local sql or gz file. You can sync with S3/Dropbox or deploy dump at server2 later, without lock. E.g., dump to sql.gz file:

```
mysqldump -u <db_user> --password=<db_password> -h <host> <db_name> | gzip > `date +mydbdump_%y_%m_%d.sql.gz`
```