# The same mysql database on Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: mysql, linux, database, windows, ubuntu

I want to use same database on my Ubuntu installation as of Windows 7, I've already changed datadir in my /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf and /etc/mysql/my.cnf to Windows path like this: `/media/Data/xampp/mysql/data` but it still doesn't work how can I connect to database from Windows installation?

Comment: Dump the database using a client and import it into your new host

Comment: But I want to have this database dynamically, I mean when I edit some rows on Ubuntu it should change on Windows too. Is there any way to do it? I'm new on Ubuntu and don't know how to di it.

Comment: Cronjobs should do the job. They trigger commands on a set interval. Ref. mysqldump

Comment: Can you explain or give me an example? As I said I'm new on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You could "update" databases on a set interval using cronjobs.

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312514/how-to-sync-a-mysql-databases-between-two-remote-databases-without-mysql-databa) is how to "sync" 2 databases on remote hosts
- [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) is how to establish cronjobs

A disadvantage would be that you'd have to dump the entire database which could dramatically slow down the process.

Please note that those articles are exclusively related to some linux distros.

Comment: But I have the systems on same computer so what should I type in <server 1 hostname>?

Comment: Do you have your Ubuntu distro on a VM? (Do they run concurently?)

Comment: No, I have installed Ubuntu next to Windows 7.

Comment: Then it's nearly impossible since they use different filesystems. Think of a point of centralization like an intermediate point that stores db data until one of your machines collect it (a remote worker or something simpler but manual: flash drives). The problem is a bit too complex especially because it lacks context.

Comment: Hmm so I can't do it?